# Visual studio 2013 web publish to web deploy 3.0

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

Is it possible to publish a web application to a server with web deploy 3.0 from visual studio 2013 ? I know that visual studio 2013 ships with web deploy 3.5, but I was unable to find any information if I am going to be able to publish to web deploy 3.0

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it work?

Comment: it was a while ago, but as far as I remember it did work. Unfortunately I am not sure.